# Best way to ensure decimal interpretation of string with leading zeros?

Tags: perl, radix, octal, leading-zero, type-coercion

I have some simple data with leading zeros, and I want to interpolate some additional values.  Something like this:

`$ printf "C011=4\nC015=8\n" | perl -ne '/C(\d\d\d)=(.*)/; $l{$1}=$2 }{ $l{13}=($l{15}-$l{11})/2+$l{11}; printf "C%03d=%f\n",$_,$l{$_} for keys %l;'`

```
C011=4.000000
C013=0.000000
C015=8.000000
```

Okay.  Perl's not matching `11` to `011`

In the simple case above, you might think, hey, whatever, let's use the leading zeros in the hash keys for the arithmetic:

`$ printf "C011=4\nC015=8\n" | perl -ne '/C(\d\d\d)=(.*)/; $l{$1}=$2 }{ $l{013}=($l{015}-$l{011})/2+$l{011}; printf "C%03d=%f\n",$_,$l{$_} for keys %l;'`

```
C011=4.000000
C011=0.000000
C015=8.000000
```

Here I apparently have as keys the string 011 which `printf` turns into 11, and the octal number 013, which printf turns into 11.  And the lookup of the `011` and `015` values *still* failed.

What are the options in perl for avoiding the behavior of numbers with leading zeros (and no 9's) being interpreted as octal?  I want the hash keys to have their appropriate decimal value.

I have a workaround.  I just want to see if it's the most succinct solution.  Something like a global don't-do-this, I'm never using octals.

Expected output:

```
C011=4.000000
C013=6.000000
C015=8.000000
```

Comment: **Helpful tip**: To drop leading zeroes from a string which is otherwise a valid number do this: `$s=$s+0; # Just add zero to it` But first check your string is a valid number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with the original code is that hash keys are strings, and `011` and `11` are different strings.

---

Solution 1: Use the correct string.

```
perl -ne'
   /C(\d\d\d)=(.*)/; $l{$1}=$2;
   END {
      $l{"013"}=($l{"015"}-$l{"011"})/2+$l{"011"};
      printf "C%s=%f\n",$_,$l{$_} for sort keys %l;
   }
'
```

It's simpler to include the `C`.

```
perl -ne'
   /(C\d\d\d)=(.*)/; $l{$1}=$2;
   END {
      $l{C013}=($l{C015}-$l{C011})/2+$l{C011};
      printf "%s=%f\n",$_,$l{$_} for sort keys %l;'
   }
'
```

---

Solution 2: Convert the captured strings to match those produced by the code.

Replace `$l{$1}=$2` with `$l{0+$1}=$2`.

This will numify `011` to eleven, then stringify that to `11`.

This supports any number of leading zeros.

Comment: Solution2 is what I was looking for.  In my actual program, I have to use the keys themselves as numbers in other arithmetic, so it's the `0+` numification that I was searching for.   I was actually using `sprintf "%d",$1` where you have suggested `0+$1`

Comment: In Perl, scalars are coerced into numbers where a number is expected (addition, multiplication, `sprintf %d`, etc), and coerced into strings when a string is expected (`print`, hash key, etc).  `sprintf %d` is fine, but `0+` is cheaper and a bit more self-documenting (because noone would use `0+` for anything else).

Comment: @ysth, I do use `END { }` personally. Saving 4 chars is no reason to use `}{`. The `}{` is from the OP's code. But you know what, I already added a `sort`, so I'll have the program use `END { }`.

Comment: In the real program, I have `sub n {$a <=> $b};` once and `sort n keys %l... ` wherever I need a numerical sort.  Numbers with different numbers of characters don't sort well.  But that and the eskimo kiss operator weren't the point.

Comment: `sort`''s default sort function works fine where I used it because the numbers were padded to the same length using zeroes